# iOS8 & xcode6 no longer plays sound

Tags: audio, ios8, xcode6, audiotoolbox

I'm having a problem that appeared after the big update to iOS 8 and XCode6.

When I try to play sound with AudioToolBox nothing comes out the speakers.  I am using the simulator.

I have two variants of the function that plays the sound.

```
-(void)playSound:(NSString *)fileName
{
    SystemSoundID soundEffet = [self soundEffect];
    NSURL *soundURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:fileName withExtension:@"mp3"];
    NSString *URLString = [soundURL absoluteString];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:URLString])
    {
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)soundURL, &soundEffet);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundEffet);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error, file not found: %@", fileName);
    }
}
```

This fails the file exists at path check.

```
-(void)playSound:(NSString *)fileName
{
    SystemSoundID soundEffet = [self soundEffect];
    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType:@"mp3"];
    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:URLString])
    {
        NSURL *pathURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)pathURL, &soundEffet);
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundEffet);
    } else {
        NSLog(@"error, file not found: %@", fileName);
    }
}
```

This one just doesn't play anything.

I am very sure that the file name that I am using is correct.

Does anyone have any ideas about what changed so that these no longer work?  And most important: how do I fix this?

Comment: same issue with me :(

Comment: AudioServicesPlaySystemSound did neither work for me. What worked was     NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"XXX" ofType: @"mp3"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
    self.backgroundAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&error];
    if (self.backgroundAudioPlayer != nil) {
        self.backgroundAudioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1; //infinite loop
        [self.backgroundAudioPlayer play];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Cannot play background song");
    }

Comment: Sadly, that did not work for me Reinhard.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out!  (Cue the flailing kermit arms.) Reinhard Manner's comment is what pointed me in the right direction.
I did indeed end up using AVAudioPlayer.  Here's  what I ended up with.

```
-(void)playSound:(NSString *)fileName
{
    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:fileName ofType: @"mp3"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
    soundPlayer =[[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:nil];
    if (soundPlayer != nil)
    {
        [soundPlayer play];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"could not play with file %@", fileName);
    }
}
```

Not included here is the soundPlayer synthesized at the top of the file and made a a property in the .h file.

I still don't know why AudioToolbox stopped working.  But this is what works, and I'm going with it.

Also, Reinhard Manner, you may want to post that type of thing as an answer next time, so that you can get more credit!